# can we have commands and functions of console and win32 c++ interchanged?

Tags: c++, winapi, console

I have developed communication program with  c++ console programming, it is complete and works fine. Now I need to change my code for some real-time purpose, where I need to use the previous and add further and generate the .avi movie (most probably with BMP images).

The thing is the that as I have understood that the movie can only be generated with win32 c++ and not console programming?

hence
1. Can I use the same code (with necessary changes ofcourse) and the APIs that I was using in console programming with the win32 programming?

1. Can I go the other way around, i.e. make the movie generation code in win32 c++ and later include somehow in the console program. If yes, any idea?

any other idea is also appreciable

Comment: Being a console program means the program inherits access to its parent's console, or creates a console of its own. It doesn't seem to restrict the program from using any other part of the Win32 API at all.

Comment: @Jerry Coffin: indeed; console apps can use the rest of the Win32 API just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no difference to Win32 programming and "console" programming - you can use both at the same time.  The only difference is the main entry function you're using (most often main vs. WinMain).  So, don't bother setting up a new project if the console app could be adjusted more easily.

In fact, console apps can even make windows, and a window-based app can create it's own consoles as well.  And there's no difference to Win32 C++ and console C++ (apart from the main entry function you're using I've mentioned and the idiomatic way to communicate input and output).

Comment: thanks for reply. but for example some statements, for example printf() to be the most common does not work with the windows based system (unless we call console, after which I guess it will, but haven;t tried) and similar others. I think the viceversa is also same

Comment: A console app can call `MessageBox` just fine - make sure to `#include <windows.h>` as well.  About `printf`: it writes to the standard output for the process, which shows up on the console.  So if the process doesn't have a console you have to make one first.  Use [AllocConsole](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681944%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to get you a console in a non-console application, and use [freopen](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/58667) to make `printf` write to that console (like `freopen( "CON", "w", stdout );`).